# writing custom control or widget in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

I want to build custome control or widget using Angular.
I know how to build form using basic controls such as textbox, button etc. using Angular-Formly.
Please, help me out how to do this.
Suppose i want to create Slider on my page based on json then what are the steps I need to follow to create it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend that you take a look at the resources at [learn.angular-formly.com](http://learn.angular-formly.com/). There's a free egghead.io lesson about creating custom types with angular-formly. There's also [this example](http://angular-formly.com/#/example/custom-types/custom-templates) that could be helpful.

Comment: Thanks kentcdodds for your help :)